# How can I stop my form from adding a record if it already exists in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, duplicates

I have created a script which already work to add a player into the team database, as well as sending of an email to someone to check. However I would like to add an exception where if the record already exists an error message appears on the screen.

I have tried using the not exists statement as well as the alternative which is an if statement. But nothing happens in the database apart from adding an empty row, non of the data is added. I am using php to do this.

```
<?php
include("file:///C|/Users/Duncan-PC2/Documents/tugay/connect.php");

$name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]));
$surname = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["surname"]));   
$dob = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["dob"]));
$email = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]));
$phone = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["contact_no"]));
$nat = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["nat"]));
$address = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]));
$transfer = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["transfer"]));
$team_name = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["team_name"]));
$licence = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["licence"]));
$division = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["division"]));
$img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM teams WHERE name = '$name' and    surname = '$surname'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO teams (id, name, surname, dob, email, contact_no, nat, address, transfer, team_name, licence, division, image)
    VALUES ('', '$name', '$surname', '$dob', '$email', '$phone', '$nat', '$address', '$transfer', '$team_name', '$licence', '$division', '$img')");

    $to = 'lisanssekreteri@gmail.com  '; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
    $email_subject = "New Player for $team_name Added";
    $email_body = "$team_name have added a new player! \n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name $surname\n\n Please go into the system and check this Player. ";
    $headers = "From: TCFF PLAYER REGISTRATION\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);  


    echo ('<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <h1 class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> PLEASE READ: This player has been added, please go to the red tab labelled with non approved players! Please do not attempt to add this player again. THIS PLAYER IS NOW APART OF YOUR TEAM AND WILL BE ACTIVATED SOON please be patient!</h1>
    <h1 class="col-lg-10">Thankyou This Player Has Been Succefully Added To Your Team! 

                    </div></h1>
    <span class="col-lg-10">
    <button class="btn-lg btn btn-danger" onclick="history.go(-2);">  Click Here To Go Back To Admin Panel, Please do not try to re-add this player!</button>
    </span>');

} else {

    echo ("<h1>This Player Already Exists or is apart of another team</h1>");

}
```

Comment: Add a unique constraint on the column.

Comment: Why are you using archaic code? Welcome to the 21st century.

Comment: *"How can I stop my form from adding a record"* - What form? Plus, no idea how you're accessing that file.

Comment: and what type of *funky* syntax is this? `file:///C|/`

Comment: It seems you're not in a hurry for this and have either found your problem or left the question. You've been given comments and an answer. I for one, won't be able to help you out with this. I don't stick around questions for hours/days on end. Good luck with this.

Comment: I don't know where you got this code from, but it's awful, outdated and insecure. Looking at the comments it clearly isn't your own code, so the best I can suggest is to throw it away and find something a bit more up-to-date to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent double inserts by doing a `SELECT` query first checking if a record already exists. take a look at the following example:

```
SELECT id
FROM some_table
WHERE something='bla';

// If the above query does not return any results, you can insert.
INSERT INTO some_table (something) VALUES ('bla');
```

#### Edit

This probably won't fix the problem but I find it good practice to do my query strings as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM teams WHERE name = '".$name."' and    surname = '".$surname."'");
```

Comment: I noticed your edit: `'$var'` and `'".$var."'` both produce the same thing. So, that's not it. The question lacks too much detail.

Comment: To give any further answer I will need to know if an sql error has been thrown.